# Samba, files readable but not writable

Tags: samba

Environment: PC with Windows 8.1 and Raspberry Pi with Raspbian. On PC, the whole `C:` drive is shared.

Needed: Minimal possibility to move .jar files developed on PC to Raspberry. Some more file management from PC on Raspberry would be nice: removing files, renaming files, making directories, etc. would be nice.

I modified the default smb.conf file as follows:

```
[global]
workgroup= MS-HOME
wins support = yes
security=share
usershare max shares=100

[homes]
read only=no
writable=yes
create mask =0777
guest ok =yes
directory mask = 0777

[pihome]
comment= Pi Home
path=/home/pi
browsable=yes
writable=yes
only guest=no
create mask =0777
create directory=0777 
public=yes
```

Now, from my PC I can e.g. read a text file, but I cannot update it. Also, I cannot create a directory; not authorized.

What is wrong is my smb.conf?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you wish to have total control (read/write/create...) on the 'pihome' share.
Then, use the following:

`[pihome] 
    comment= Pi Home 
    path=/home/pi 
    browsable=yes 
    writable=yes 
    force create mode = 0777 
    force directory mode = 0777 
    public=yes`

About the 'homes' section: this is normally referring to the directory that belongs to a specific user on Unix (normally /home/uid).  As such, it is intended to be only available per user (which means you have to enter uid + password)
I would therefore leave it unchanged from the default value:

`[homes]
        comment = Unix user directory
        valid users = %S
        read only = No
        browseable = No`